Marketing Automation button does not show on launchpad
I have enabled xDB on my local Sitecore 10.1 instance but the Marketing Automation button does not display on the launchpad. We do have the same versions on our other servers and they do have this button.
Is there an additional setting for this to be enable or should this show automatically?


Enabling/Disabling of Marketing Automation button is handled from the app dependency section under Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Client.config as below.
 <appDependencies>
    <marketingAutomation dependencyEvaluator="Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Client.DependencyEvaluator, Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Client">
        <!--Hides MA application button from Sitecore launchpad in case if XDB is disabled.-->
        <app id="{3A86E677-5AD1-4315-B7B5-EFA11988119A}" name="Marketing Automation" />
    </marketingAutomation>
 </appDependencies>

Check inside above class contains 2 conditions.

XDB is Enabled
License file has the module Sitecore.Automation

Since you have already enabled XDB, can you check if the license file contains module 'Sitecore.Automation'.
Hope this helps!!!

Thank You @ckhanna! The license file was the culprit and has been updated.
